# Limit of a Sine Function

Tags: limits, functions

Calculate via the limit definition:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \frac {\pi}2^-} \frac{\sin^2(\frac {\pi}2-x)}{\sqrt{\pi-2x}},$$

I tried to calculate this limit using the definition of a limit and got stuck. My guess was that I need to somehow manipulate the argument to something like

$$\frac{\sin(\frac {\pi}2-x)}{\frac {\pi}2-x}\frac {\sin(\frac {\pi}2-x) \cdot(\frac {\pi}2-x)^{\frac 1 2}}{\sqrt2}$$

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: It may help to let $\frac{\pi}{2}-x=t$. Then you will be on more familiar ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to let $\frac{\pi}{2}-x=t$. Then you will be on more familiar  ground.

For $t$ positive and not too large, we have $0\lt \sin t\lt t$. So our expression is positive and less than $t^{3/2}/\sqrt{2}$, which is less than $t$ if $t\lt 1$.

Comment: Thanks. So in this case, could I simply choose for every $\epsilon > 0, \delta = min\{\epsilon, 1/2\}$ ? Since as long as $0 < t < \delta$ then the expression should be smaller than $\epsilon$?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, that choice is fine. Good about the $\min$ part! If some joker gave us $\epsilon=2015$, then taking $\delta=\epsilon$ would land us in trouble.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sin^2 (\pi/2-x)}{\sqrt {\pi/2 -x}} = (\sin(\pi/2 -x))^{3/2}\cdot \left ( \frac{\sin (\pi/2-x)}{\pi/2 -x}\right )^{1/2} \to 0\cdot 1^{1/2} = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2-} \frac{sin^2(\pi/2-x)}{\sqrt{\pi-2x}}
$$
Take $t=\pi/2-x$,
$$
\lim\limits_{t \to 0^+} \frac{sin^2(t)}{\sqrt{2t}}
$$
$$
\lim\limits_{t \to 0^+} \frac{1-cos(2t)}{2\sqrt{2t}}
$$
Using L'Hospital's Rule,
$$
\lim\limits_{t \to 0^+} \frac{2sin(2t)}{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t}}}
$$
$$
=0
$$

Comment: In your second line you want $t \to 0^+.$